# How to read log messages from console in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I have a requirement like to read the application log messages from console.Is there any provision in xcode to get it or any API can record it while launching the app.

Regards,
sk

Comment: `NSLog` does not meet ur requirement?

Comment: No .Whatever log(Using NSLog) messages showing in console after launching the application that logs I want to read  from console by using some API.